# Jquery Unfocus field if value equals

Tags: javascript, jquery

What I am trying to achieve in the below code is when "0" has been entered into the input field it gets unfocused and other stuff triggers.

```js
$(".val-0").keyup(function() {
  if ($(this).val() === 0) {
    $(this).blur();
    // Do other Stuffss
  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input class="val-0" type="number">
```

Answer (score 1):

You are missing an opening quotation on the class name, for one thing.

For another, you are using `===` to compare which requires same data type (strict comparison). `input.val()` returns data of type `string` not `integer`.

Deeper explanation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/523643/difference-between-and-in-javascript).

You want to compare using `$(this).val() == 0)` or `$(this).val() === '0')`

```js
$(".val-0").keyup(function() {
  if ($(this).val() == 0) {
    $(this).blur();
    // Do other Stuffss
  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input class="val-0" type="number">
```

Answer (score 0):

Due to some reason you cannot attached keyup event to input type of number. I tried to put working example here. I hope it will help you.

```js
$(".val-0").keyup(function(event) {
console.log(event.which + ", " + $(this).val());
  if ($(this).val() === 0) {
    $(this).blur();
    console.log($(this));
  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input class="val-0" type="text" />
```